# What is a specific command for zipping and compressing multiple files with lzma2 on linux command line?

Tags: linux, syntax, command, compression, lzma

Can you give an example for compressing files with lzma2? 
I searched on Google but I didn't find any examples that I could understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `lzma` binary or the `xz` with the `--format=lzma` argument.,

If you want to compress a set of files, I would recommend using tar to glue them together and then lzma, as for example:

```
$ tar --lzma -cf foo.tar.lzma file1 file2 ...
$ file foo.tar.lzma
foo.tar.lzma: LZMA compressed data, streamed
```

Comment: it seems that you don't have etc. Try /etc or something like that.

Comment: I tried it here and it worked:
tar --lzma -cf foo.tgz etc boot

root@localhost:/# file foo.tgz 
foo.tgz: LZMA compressed data, streamed

Comment: Great. Compression algorithm is a space/CPU usage trade off.

Answer (score 1):

The `XZ Utils` package is installed in most Linux distributions and is becoming the de facto standard compression format. The tool compresses with LZMA2. Usage is as simple as it gets,

```
$ xz <file>
```

To produce `file.xz`.

Comment: And if you want to compress and zip 3 files or directories to one file and you want to give it an different name, what is the command then?

Comment: You would use `tar` if you want to compress multiple files. There are lots of examples on the man pages for `xz` and `tar`. This is really a question for Unix/Linux as it doesn't relate to programming.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
sudo tar --lzma -cf newname.tar.lzma  file1 file2 file3
```

Replace the `newname` with the new name you want to give to the file
and replace `file1 file2 file3...` with the names of the files you want to zip and compress.